# Different behaviour of delete keyword on global variables

Tags: javascript

Please consider the following snippet (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ej28/)):

```
​var a;

​a = 1;
console.log(delete a​); // prints 'false'

​b = 1;
console.log(delete b);​ // prints 'true'​​​​
```

Why does the `delete` keywords behave differently on the global variables `a` and `b`?

Comment: MDN says Returns false only if the property exists and cannot be deleted. It returns true in all other cases. After deleting, try testing the actual values. You'll see that `a` was not deleted.

Comment: @Nile: Yeah, the behaviour is different. I don't see how this *explains* anything.

Comment: It behaves differently _because it is defined to_? What else do you want?

Comment: @Eric: Maybe an explanation of *why* it was defined to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

A global variable (without `var`) is a property on the global object (typically `window`), so can be deleted.

A `var` is not a global variable, but a local variable in the outer scope - not a property of the global object - so `delete` does not delete it. From those docs:

```
x = 42;     // creates the property x on the global object
var y = 43; // declares a new variable, y

delete x;   // returns true  (x is a property of the global object and can be deleted)
delete y;   // returns false (delete doesn't affect variable names)
```

Comment: Declared and undeclared global variables are both properties of the global object. They only differ based on the value of the `configurable` attribute. For more info, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16007360/1306809

Answer (score 3):

MDN says delete returns false only if the property exists and cannot be deleted. It returns true in all other cases. After deleting, try testing the actual values. You'll see that `a` was not deleted. This is because, as the MDN page says, `delete` will not affect variable names.

> It has no effect on variable or function names.

(i.e., defined with `var` and not off the global object)

Take a look at the examples on the following page.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 2):

From [mozilla docs about var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) :

*The difference is that a declared variable is a non-configurable property of the global object while an undeclared is configurable.*

`var a;` --> This is a declared variable, because you are using `var`, so it's not configurable.

`a = 6;` --> This is an undeclared variable, because you are not using `var`, so it's configurable.

both syntaxes above will end up with a var named `a` attached as a property of the global object (`window` typically) and properties has these attributes:

- **Writable**. If false, the value of the property can not be changed.
- **Configurable**. If false, any attempts to delete the property or change its attributes (Writable, Configurable, or Enumerable) will fail.
- **Enumerable**. If true, the property will be iterated over when a user does for (var prop in obj){} (or similar).

that is extracted from [ecmascript5 objects and properties](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/) , and as you can read, the `configurable` attribute of the variable in question  affects whether the variable can or cannot be deleted.

Comment: +1 This is the best answer for the question. The accepted answer is not entirely accurate.

Answer (score 0):

"var a" means it cannot be accessed from anywhere outside of the current block, thus deleting it *WOULD* mean *UNDECLARE* (not same as undefined), thus allowing to write "var a" again in the same block (error).

Allowed usages (MDN):

```
delete object.property 
delete object['property'] 
delete object[index] 
delete property
```

It's like GOTO and unstructured programming, where you might need to manually clean up resources, it's kind of ~Destructor in C (though not the same). You can delete an object like ~a(); but you cannot "'UNDECLARE' a variable" like "int i".