# Effect of declared and undeclared variables

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, variable-declaration

What is the major difference between JavaScript declared and undeclared variables, since
the delete operator doesn't work on declared variables?

```
 var y = 43;     // declares a new variable
 x = 42;

 delete x;       // returns true  (x is a property of the global object and can be deleted)
 delete y;       // returns false (delete doesn't affect variable names)
```

Why does this happen? Variables declared globally are also the properties of the window object, so why can't it be deleted?

Comment: The undeclared ones are called "implicit globals". Looking up the term should indicate what's wrong with them.

Comment: comment if the link doesn't answer your question..

Comment: @asifrc I never knew that

Comment: @asifrc I am new to web-programing I was about to ask this question but you posted good link answers me.

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433223/different-behaviour-of-delete-keyword-on-global-variables

Comment: @Maizere there's nothing wrong with posting duplicates unless it indicates the lack of effort. Duplicates that are worded differently than their targets are useful as search targets.

Comment: It was the second google result for 'js var' lolz..

Comment: But globally declared variable are also the properties of window object

Comment: @asifrc I never new that o-0

Comment: Voted "reopen" as this question addresses different matters, compared to the link given on top.

Comment: @Maizere how is that a different one? Which are the matters this question addresses the other does not?

Comment: @Maizere (backspace..) what Jan said..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Declared and undeclared global variables

The mechanism for storing and accessing them is the same, but JavaScript treats them differently in some cases based on the value of the `configurable` attribute (described below). In regular usage, they should behave the same.

### Both exist in the global object

Below are some comparisons of *declared* and *undeclared* global variables.

```
var declared = 1;  // Explicit global variable (new variable)
undeclared   = 1;  // Implicit global variable (property of default global object)

window.hasOwnProperty('declared')    // true
window.hasOwnProperty('undeclared')  // true

window.propertyIsEnumerable('declared')    // true
window.propertyIsEnumerable('undeclared')  // true

window.declared     // 1
window.undeclared   // 1

window.declared   = 2;
window.undeclared = 2;

declared     // 2
undeclared   // 2

delete declared     // false
delete undeclared   // true
delete undeclared   // true (same result if delete it again)

delete window.declared     // false
delete window.undeclared   // true (same result if delete it yet again)
delete window.undeclared   // true (still true)
```

Both *declared* and *undeclared* global variables are properties of the `window` object (the default global object). Neither one is inherited from a different object through the prototype chain. They both exist directly in the `window` object (since [`window.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) returns `true` for both).

### The configurable attribute

For *declared* global variables, the `configurable` attribute is `false`. For *undeclared* global variables, it's `true`. The value of the `configurable` attribute can be retrieved using the [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) method, as shown below.

```
var declared = 1;
undeclared = 1;

(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'declared')).configurable     // false
(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'undeclared')).configurable   // true
```

If the `configurable` attribute of a property is true, the attributes of the property can be changed using the [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) method, and the property can be deleted using the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator. Otherwise, the attributes cannot be changed, and the property cannot be deleted in this manner.

In [non-strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode), the `delete` operator returns `true` if the property is configurable, and returns `false` if it's non-configurable.

### Summary

**Declared global variable**

- Is a property of the default global object (`window`)
- The property attributes *cannot* be changed.
- *Cannot* be deleted using the `delete` operator

**Undeclared global variable**

- Is a property of the default global object (`window`)
- The property attributes *can* be changed.
- *Can* be deleted using the `delete` operator

### See also

- [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)
- [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)
- [Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)
- [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)
- [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)

Comment: delete window.m//false :is this becoz of the configurable  attribute of the property "m"  set to false?

Comment: @Maizere: Yes! That was the final missing piece of the puzzle! Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer above with some additional info, and edited it to make things a little more clear.

Comment: @Matt Coughlin In chrome 55 console, I am seeing an interesting behavior where if the `var name = 'bob`` then `delete` returns true.  but `var name = 1` delete returns false.  Why is there a difference between strings and numbers.  Is it because the string is coverted to an object while the number is not?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is when you're declaring variables inside a function. If you use `var` when you're declaring a variable inside a function, then that variable becomes a local variable. However, if you don't use `var`, then the variable becomes a global variable no matter where you declare it (inside or outside a function).

Answer (score 1):

When any variable is created via Variable Declaration in **JavaScript** , these properties are created with "**DontDelete**" attribute , which basically means that variable you created cannot be Deleted using "delete" expression. All the functions, arguments , function parameters by default are created with this DontDelete attribute. You can think of DontDelete as a flag.

```
var y = 43;
delete y;         //returns false because it is has a DontDelete attribute
```

Whereas Undeclared assignment doesn't set any attributes like **DontDelete** . So when we apply **delete** operator on this undeclared variable , it returns true.

```
x = 42;
delete x;        //returns true because it doesn't have a DontDelete attribute
```

The difference between property assignment and variable declaration — latter one sets DontDelete, whereas former one doesn’t. That's why undeclared assignment creates a deletable property.

[Link on how exactly delete operator works](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#built_ins_and_dontdelete)

Answer (score 0):

delete is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect on variable or function names.

In your case x = 42; declares variable X and makes it the property of the Global object. So it returns true.

And var y = 43; declares a global variable which is not part of any object so it returns false.

Comment: globally declared variables are also the properties of window object.try this var x=10; alert(window.x)

Comment: @Maizere Setting properties on the window object is equivalent to creating global variables which lend up in global name spaces. So even though the properties are in the window object but in global namespace delete works on them...