# why leave a variable undeclared in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

Just starting out learning JS. I understand defining variables. Why leave one undeclared? Does it help when constructing if/then statements?

Comment: This might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985875/effect-of-declared-and-undeclared-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep it can "help when constructing if/then statements?" the value of undefined is false. so:

```
 if ( myVar )
```

means if its got a value true if not false

but its best to do:

```
var myVar;
```

which still is false not declaring may give a error in a older browser

im not sure happens if you already have a global "var i;" and then try using one in a loop, i think it will just make you lose the global "i" for the new one.

Comment: `the value of undefined is false`; _undefined_ is falsy, but `undefined !== false`

Comment: @PaulS. true (lol) but it will still work for a "if(undeclaredVariable)"

Answer (score 3):

> Why leave one undeclared?

```
function foo() {
    var i = 0; // local variable
    j = 1;     // global variable
}
foo();
i; // undefined
j; // 1
function bar() {
    var k; // local variable
    k = 2; // still local
}
bar();
k; // undefined
```

If `foo` is in `"use strict"` mode, it will cause a `ReferenceError: j is not defined` unless another `j` is defined higher up the scope chain, because there was no `var` for the `j`.

Comment: as far as i know you cant declare a global variable **inside** a function and "j=1;" (if its not a error) will be a local variable

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight If you don't believe it, try the code I've posted here, followed by a check to see if there is a global `j` and report back :-) I believe that the `j;` outside of the _function_ as in my example is sufficient proof, though.

Comment: It is true that `j` will not necessarily become global if there is a `var j` higher in scope but not globally, though.

Comment: your right i tried it