# what is the reason of " events.js:174 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event " gulp error message?

Tags: gulp, jasmine, gulp-jasmine

I'm tryig to write a code that test another functionality code using jasmine testing framework and gulp
But i'm new in the Gulp field and i'm encountering the following issue
my code is :

```
/*eslint-env node */

const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');
const jasmineBrowser = require('gulp-jasmine-browser');


gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'lint'], function() {
    gulp.watch('sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['lint']);

    browserSync.init({
        server: './'
    });
});

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp
        .src('sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(
            autoprefixer({
                browsers: ['last 2 versions']
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return (
        gulp
            .src(['js/**/*.js'])
            // eslint() attaches the lint output to the eslint property
            // of the file object so it can be used by other modules.
            .pipe(eslint())
            // eslint.format() outputs the lint results to the console.
            // Alternatively use eslint.formatEach() (see Docs).
            .pipe(eslint.format())
            // To have the process exit with an error code (1) on
            // lint error, return the stream and pipe to failOnError last.
            .pipe(eslint.failOnError())
    );
});

gulp.task('tests', function() {
    return gulp
        .src('tests/spec/extraSpec.js')
        .pipe(jasmineBrowser.specRunner({ console: true }))

        .pipe(jasmineBrowser.headless({ driver: 'chrome' }));
});
```

And when i execute the following command in the terminal `gulp tests`
I get this error message

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:\Users\atlas\Desktop\ud892\Lesson 2\node_modules\gulp-jasmine-browser\lib\runners\chrome_runner ENOENT
```

what is the reason of this issue? and how can i solve it?
Taking into consideration that i'm using windows7 and , i have read all the relevant stackoverflow posts but neither of them has the answer.

Comment: In `sloppy` mode `Undeclared variables are always global.`

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985875/effect-of-declared-and-undeclared-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't create a variable with `var/let/const` it is created as a global variable in the global scope and it will be accessible from anywhere in your code.

If you were to use [`strict` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), using an uninitialised variable (as you have done above) would result in a `ReferenceError` error since it does not yet exist.